# JavaScript value not evaluated correctly when in a variable, but works correctly as a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not sure why this evaluation differs when it is only in a variable, versus a string. I don't see any logic.

```
const numRegex = /hundred|thousand|million|billion|trillion/ig;

const isNum = string => numRegex.test(string)


var word = 'hundred';
console.log('isNum with string:', isNum('hundred')); // true
console.log('isNum with variable:', isNum(word));    // false
console.log('words are equal:', word === 'hundred'); // true
```

Comment: The issue is the order, not whether it's a variable or not. You can copy the first console log, and will get the same results. You are reusing the regex, and due to the `g` flag, the regex' `lastIndex` gets updated, and stays changed in any subsequent calls.

Comment: @Ivar thanks, I couldn't find it…

Answer (score 3):

`isNum` is returning `false` when it's called a second time on the same string. Change the order and see the same thing:

```
const numRegex = /hundred|thousand|million|billion|trillion/ig;

const isNum = string => numRegex.test(string)


var word = 'hundred';
console.log('isNum with variable:', isNum(word));    // true
console.log('isNum with string:', isNum('hundred')); // false
console.log('words are equal:', word === 'hundred'); // true
```

The `g` flag remembers where the last match was. Remove it to fix the problem:

```
const numRegex = /hundred|thousand|million|billion|trillion/i;
```

[Mozilla talks more about this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Using_a_regular_expression_with_the_sticky_flag):

> The [sticky flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky) indicates that the regular expression performs sticky matching in the target string by attempting to match starting at [RegExp.prototype.lastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex).